# What programming language to use to develop a cross platform game? (including facebook/web browser)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, browser

Sorry for my bad english in advance.

& i know, these are noob questions but i really need your help

So i have a project to do in 4-6 month, it's an eLearning platform/game using quiz system in which every player earn points & check his rank among all players in this game, the game should be integrated in facebook as an app, but also have to be used as an "application" on android phone, tablets (& iOS if it's possible too), & must require a connection to the facebook account before starting the game.

Do i have to code the game for every platform? is there any possibility to code one app for all of them? I've done some research on the internet, i think i have two options: either using flash & action script, or html5/css/js, are these tools are suitable for my project? i know some html5 & css already, but the game doesn't have to be a brower game on the mobile/tablet version.
I found a framework called phonegab that may help, do you think it's suitable?

Thanks

Comment: This kind of questions do not belong on SO IMHO.

Comment: This is off-topic for this site, see [Multi-platform Mobile Development?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/181309/multi-platform-mobile-development)

Comment: @alex, alright, i'll put my question there, thanks

Comment: Its off topic there as well I'm afraid, that's why the linked question was closed.

Comment: Hi here's simple and reliable way: Use HTML5/JavaScript with the Phaser game framework: http://phaser.io. Publish cross-platform using Cocoon (support for this is built-in to Phaser). Avoid Phonegap, it's too slow for games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a web-application using HtML5/PHP/Javascript (and/or other languages for the back-end: rails, python, java etc.) is the way to go if you're just starting out. While not as fluid or fast as native applications, you can build the web application and it will work on both iOS and Android, and you should be able to wrap it into a Facebook app.